# Downloading a blank excel spread sheet stored in a folder on a server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I stored an excel file in a folder on my server and I want to download
it when user clicks a button from my client app.

Here is my controller action

```
        public IActionResult BulkSample()
        {
            try
            {
                return File(
                    fileContents: ResourceFactory.GetEmbeddedResource("sample.xlsx"),
                    contentType: "application/vnd.ms-excel",
                    fileDownloadName: "sample.xlsx");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Here is the code that is getting the file below
resFilestream is always null and return null. This way my file will not be downloaded.

what am i doing wrong here?

```
        public static class ResourceFactory 
        {
            public byte[] GetEmbeddedResource(string name)
            {
                var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                var resourceName = $"Parent.Samples.{name}";

                byte[] bytes;

                using (Stream resFilestream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
                {
                    if (resFilestream == null)
                        return null;

                    bytes = new byte[resFilestream.Length];
                    resFilestream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }

                return bytes;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If your embedded resource is under a folder, the `resourceName` should also include that. For example, if the sample.xlsx is under `excelfiles` folder: `Parent.Samples.excelfiles.{name}` And it is best to provide this while passing the resource name, like `ResourceFactory.GetEmbeddedResource("excelfiles.sample.xlsx");`

Comment: Yes that is in place. All I get is Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'fileContents'). Not sure why

Comment: Is the file marked as Embedded Resource? Is this .net core or .net fw? Which version? Your title says "stored in a folder", this is not how embedded resources work. Do you mean something like reading the file from disk?

Comment: How do you mark a file as embedded resource? This is webapi asp.net core. I have a common project and inside it is a folder and inside the folder is the file with the xlsx extension.

Comment: Oh, if .net core see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.1#manifestembeddedfileprovider). In the referred section, it explains how to include files as embedded resources.

Comment: I see. So you have to manually include the files in the csproj file? That might be the cause of my problem.  There is a "Remove" and "Include"  section in the ItemGroup. Are they both important?

Comment: So you have to manually include the files in the csproj file? yes, that is true. And it is also true for Include and Remove. EmbeddedResource + Include to include the file as an embedded resource, and, Content + Remove to prevent it from being deployed physically

Comment: I did that and I am not getting a null anymore. I am testing from insomnia. I did not see an actual file downloaded in  insomnia. I just saw some funny characters on the screen. I am hoping that when I do this from a client application I should be able to see the real excel file downloaded. Is this correct?

Comment: Download the file, change the extension xlsx to zip (?, yes, open XML format and it is just a compressed folder which contains many files). If you can't do that, see if the first two characters are P and K, and a few bytes later, see [Content_Types].xml

Comment: The correct media type (`contentType: `) in your code for open XML excel files is this by the way: `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: How did you download it? If you are using a browser, it should be opened or at least downloaded. What is the File class in your code? Is it a custom class? Please also see the response headers. (using developer tools, or Fiddler, etc.)

Comment: Like I said I made a call to my webapi from insomnia. I was expecting a file name which I specified in the fileDownloadName in my code above but changed the name. I will run this from my react application. Thanks a lot.